# cannot call method from a simple module in JS

Tags: javascript, module, scope

I am trying to get an array (_posts) to be passed from within my module (Tweeter ) ,
by using  getPosts function to return it when invoked.

when I try to print it/pass it- it just prints the function's code instead of returning the array.

```js
const Tweeter = function() {
  const _posts = [{
      text: "First post!",
      id: "p1",
      comments: [{
          id: "c1",
          text: "First comment on first post!"
        },
        {
          id: "c2",
          text: "Second comment on first post!!"
        },
        {
          id: "c3",
          text: "Third comment on first post!!!"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: "Aw man, I wanted to be first",
      id: "p2",
      comments: [{
          id: "c4",
          text: "Don't wory second poster, you'll be first one day."
        },
        {
          id: "c5",
          text: "Yeah, believe in yourself!"
        },
        {
          id: "c6",
          text: "Haha second place what a joke."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  const getPosts = function() {
    return _posts
  }

  return {
    getPosts: getPosts
  }

}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are failing to invoke it, but you forgot to include the code where you try. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: That `getPosts()` methods looks overcomplicated. You could just as well directly return an array with the posts as a property from `Twitter()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After the definition, you need to create a new Object of Tweeter, like

```
const tweets = new Tweeter();
// now you can do
tweets.getPosts();
```

or you can simply invoke your function definition, like:

```js
const Tweeter = function() {
  const _posts = [{
      text: "First post!",
      id: "p1",
      comments: [{
          id: "c1",
          text: "First comment on first post!"
        },
        {
          id: "c2",
          text: "Second comment on first post!!"
        },
        {
          id: "c3",
          text: "Third comment on first post!!!"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: "Aw man, I wanted to be first",
      id: "p2",
      comments: [{
          id: "c4",
          text: "Don't wory second poster, you'll be first one day."
        },
        {
          id: "c5",
          text: "Yeah, believe in yourself!"
        },
        {
          id: "c6",
          text: "Haha second place what a joke."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  const getPosts = function() {
    return _posts
  }

  return {
    getPosts: getPosts
  }

}();
```

Now you can simply do, Tweeter.getPosts();

And if you are exporting this from a file, you can simply do:

```js
export const Tweeter = function() {
  const _posts = [{
      text: "First post!",
      id: "p1",
      comments: [{
          id: "c1",
          text: "First comment on first post!"
        },
        {
          id: "c2",
          text: "Second comment on first post!!"
        },
        {
          id: "c3",
          text: "Third comment on first post!!!"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      text: "Aw man, I wanted to be first",
      id: "p2",
      comments: [{
          id: "c4",
          text: "Don't wory second poster, you'll be first one day."
        },
        {
          id: "c5",
          text: "Yeah, believe in yourself!"
        },
        {
          id: "c6",
          text: "Haha second place what a joke."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  const getPosts = function() {
    return _posts
  }

  return {
    getPosts: getPosts
  }

};
```

And now you can import in other files like:

```
import {Tweeter} from './tweeter.js';

// use it like
const tweets = new Tweeter();
const posts = tweets.getPosts();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks ya zalame !  now I see my mistake- I was trying to invoke the wrong way with another function (as mentioned by Quentin) e.g. : func(tweeter.getPosts) - without using () for the 2nd function of tweeter. now i useL func(tweeter.getPosts())